# Difference of two dates display in another textbox after fetching data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my program I am fetching data from database and display it in table.

```
<tbody>
   <?php $total_time=0; ?>
   <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <?php echo $row->work;?>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="assigned_date[]" class="assigned_date" value="<?php echo $row->assigne_date;?>"  />
         </span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="last_date[]" class="last_date" value="<?php echo $row->last_date;?>"  />
         </span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="spent[]" class="spent" value="<?php echo $row->spent;?>"  />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="remaining[]" class="remaining" value="<?php echo $row->remaining;?>"  />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input  type="text" name="priority[]" value="<?php echo $row->priority;?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input  type="text" name="frequency[]" value="<?php echo $row->frequency;?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input  type="text" name="company[]" value="<?php echo $row->company;?>"  />
      </td>
      <td>
         <textarea  name="description[]" rows="2" id=""><?php echo $row->description;?></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input  type="text" name="secondry[]" value="<?php echo $row->secondry;?>"  />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input  type="text" name="director[]" value="<?php echo $row->director;?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <textarea  name="comments[]" rows="2" id=""><?php echo $row->comments;?></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
         <textarea  name="question[]" rows="2" id=""><?php echo $row->question;?></textarea>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Assigne_date and last_date column contain a date.
My Problem is I want to display difference of current date and assigne_date in spent column and difference between last_date and current date in remaining column.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var start = new Date();
    var end   = '<?php $date1=$row->assigne_date; ?>';
    var days   = Math.ceil((end - start)/1000/60/60/24);
    if( $(this).hasClass('assigned_date') ){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.spent').val(days);
    }
</script>
<script>  
var start1 = new Date();
    var end1  = '<?php $date1=$row->last_date; ?>';
    var days1   = Math.ceil((end1 - start1)/1000/60/60/24);
    if( $(this).hasClass('last_date') ){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.remaining').val(days);
    }

</script>
```

I dont know how to do this. please help me to find the solution.

Comment: What does `<?php $date1=$row->assigne_date; ?>` and `<?php $date1=$row->last_date; ?>` return? Also `$(this).closest('tr').find('.remaining').val(days)` must be `days1`, right?

Comment: @Stack Exchanger ..YES...There is multiple date which is stored in table like 2016-08-11,2016-08-13

Comment: you can also do this in php. check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static field (no client side interaction), use php to calculate the day difference.

If it's dynamic, use row index as an additional class or id for the DOM elements and have php output javascript with the jquery selectors that point to the row. Something like (substitute "id" with whatever your db table identity field is):

```
<input class="remaining row_<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
```

Now you can output javascript from php (just a selector example):

```
<?php
    echo "$('.remaining.row_" . $row->id . "').val();";
?>
```

**Try this:**

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date("2016-08-2");
var time = Math.abs(start.getTime() - end.getTime());
var days = Math.ceil(time / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(days);
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ssh33/pen/NAZYpm

```
function GetDays(end_date)
{
    var start_date = new Date();
    var time = Math.abs(start_date.getTime() - end_date.getTime());
    return Math.ceil(time / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
}

if( $(this).hasClass('assigned_date') ){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.spent').val(GetDays('<?php $date1=$row->assigne_date; ?>'));
}

if( $(this).hasClass('last_date') ){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.remaining').val(GetDays('<?php $date1=$row->last_date; ?>'));
}
```

Comment: It display 10 ..If I change the the date then it also display 10.

Comment: When I run my code and display in console then it show -17024

Comment: I added codepen, try the dates that your php returns in the textbox.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: end.getTime is not a function .. this error are showing in console

Comment: It must be a reserved word ;) I changed var names, reload the codepen. Any better? Works in Edge, Chrome, Firefox for me.

Comment: Yet another edit to address your multiple row question. What's your browser? Codepen works for me.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or codepen with your non-functioning html/js. Just copy/paste "view source" of whatever your php outputs. You could share a publicly accessible url with your test.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in php

```
<?php foreach($result as $row) {

$datetime1 = date_create($row->assigne_date);
$datetime2 = date_create($row->last_date);

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $interval->format("%d");
}
?>
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

You can prepare this date in your controller and use in view

Comment: I am not asking for single row in my code its fetching multiple row

Comment: @xr33dx you can use in loop as well. To show you I have used loop with code. You can get an idea by this how you can use in your code.